# ¿Cómo se hace un ciclo para recorrer una fila y una columna especifica de una matriz?

Tags: java

**Este es el problema:** La función *llenar_jugadas* ya la tengo pero no se como realizar la otra función, espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

> - Una función llamada Llenar_Jugadas, donde se llenan aleatoriamente las jugadas de ambos jugadores en la matriz. La función recibe el tamaño de filas y columnas y retorna la matriz llena.
> - Una función llamada Evaluar_Columnas que recibe la matriz como
>   parámetro de entrada y devuelve un vector de bytes que en la primera
>   posición tiene los puntos para J1 y en la segunda posición tiene los puntos para J2.

Para saber los puntos, en la matriz de manera vertical u horizontal debe aparecer el J1 tres veces.

**Por ejemplo:** Si en la matriz sale J1|J1|J1 en la primera fila, esto seria un punto para J1.

Si en la matriz sale:

> ```
> J1 J1 J2  
> J1 J1 J2  
> J1 J1 J2
> ```

J2 tendría 1 punto y J1 tendría 2 puntos, o sea por cada 3 veces que salga el jugador suma 1 punto, ya se que este vertical y horizontal.

Y estos puntos guardarlos en un vector, esto yo lo sabría hacer pero el proceso anterior para saber los puntos no se como realizarlo.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
public class ParcialMartes {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        int filas, columnas;
        
        filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite por favor el numero de filas que llevara la matriz: "));
        columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite por favor el numero de columnas que llevara la matriz: "));
       
        Llenar_jugadas(filas, columnas);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Fin de la ejecucion");
    }
}
public static int[][] Llenar_jugadas(int m_filas, int n_columnas){

    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    int [][] m_jugadas;
   
        m_jugadas = new int [m_filas][n_columnas];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < n_columnas; j++) {
            m_jugadas[i][j] = 1+aleatorio.nextInt(2);
           System.out.print("J"+m_jugadas[i][j]+"|");
        }
       System.out.println("");
    }
   return m_jugadas; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder comprender como se recorren las filas y las columnas es mejor siempre entender como se arman las posiciones **i** y **j** (variables que usas para recorrer tu matriz).

La **i** por ejemplo tiene estas posiciones en una matriz de 3x3:

> ```
> 0 0 0
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> ```

Y la **j** tiene las siguientes posiciones:

> ```
> 0 1 2
> 0 1 2
> 0 1 2
> ```

Si te das cuanta la variable **i** crece de forma vertical "filas" y la variable **j** crece de forma horizontal "columnas".

Ahora una matriz esta formada por la combinación de estas posiciones **i** y **j** entonces las posiciones de una matriz se verán así:

> ```
> ij ij ij        00 01 02
> ij ij ij   =>   10 11 12
> ij ij ij        20 21 22
> ```

---

Ahora respecto a tu pregunta:

> ### ¿Cómo se hace un ciclo para recorrer una fila y una columna específica de una matriz?

Pues ahora es solo jugar con las posiciones. Si tenemos la siguiente matriz de números:

> ```
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
> ```

Quisiéramos obtener **1, 4, 7** haríamos lo siguiente:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
}
```

No lo olvides la **j** es la **columna** si `j = 1` entonces te mostrará **2, 5, 8**.

---

Si quisiéramos obtener **7, 8, 9** haríamos lo siguiente:

```
int i = 2;
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
}
```

Ya que la **i** representa a las **filas**, si `i = 0` entonces obtendrías **1, 2, 3**.

Ahora ya dependerá de tu lógica el conteo recorriendo filas y columnas, que según veo seguirás utilizando dos *for* al igual que haces en el método *Llenar_jugadas*. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias bro

Comment: Men te hago una pregunta, si quiero revisar columna por columna, como hago para que el iterador j aumente hasta que llegue al final de numero de columnas?

Comment: De la misma forma que hiciste el método *Llenar_jugadas* `for (int j = 0; j < n_columnas; j++) {`. ;)

Comment: También podrías hacerlo con un *length* en la posición *i* `for (int j = 0; j < m_jugadas[i].length; j++) {`. ;)

Comment: Gracias bro, mucha ayuda.